# Как сделать добавить скрипт в автозагрузку под root правами

Tags: linux

Суть такая у меня есть скрипт на с, в нем написан приложение с графической оболочкой, но запустить его можно только root правами, мне нужно добавить этот скрипт в автозагрузку, как это сделать? Пытался добавить его через сервис, но ничего не получилось скрипт не запускается.
делал следующие команды

```
sudo nano /lib/systemd/system/runscript.service

[Unit]
Description=runscript


[Service]
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/Desktop/mqtt/mod
User=root

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

systemctl enable runscript.service

systemctl start runscript.service

sudo reboot
```

Но когда перезапускаю ввожу логи и пароль программа не запускается что не так.
Пробовал через rc.local, но файла такого нет нашел, как он выглядит создал, добавил все равно не запускает.

```
sudo nano /etc/rc.local

#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.
/home/ubuntu/Desktop/mqtt/mod

exit 0
```

У меня были папки /etc/rc0.d но там тоже нету похожих файлов
Логи 
 journalctl -u runscript.service

```
-- Logs begin at Mon 2019-05-27 08:54:08 UTC, end at Mon 2019-05-27 10:33:52 UTC
-- No entries --
```

У меня стоит граф оболочка lxde на ubuntu 18.04 пытался включить его  в автозапуск использую lxde но под root все равно не запускается
для добавление открывал файл autostart

```
 nano /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/autostart

    @lxpanel --profile LXDE
    @pcmanfm --desktop --profile LXDE
    @xscreensaver -no-splash
    @lxterminal//мое добавление
```

затем создал скрипт,в который прописал в autostart

nano /etc/xdg/autostart/lxterminal.desktop

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=LXTerminal
Type=Application
Exec= /home/ubuntu/Desktop/mqtt/mod
Terminal=false
```

если оставить так приложение запускается, но не под root

пытался изменить строчку 
 Exec= /home/ubuntu/Desktop/mqtt/mod
на
 Exec=sudo /home/ubuntu/Desktop/mqtt/mod
или
 Exec=gksu /home/ubuntu/Desktop/mqtt/mod
 но не работает

пытался использовать Xspice 
 nano /home/ubuntu/Desktop/mqtt/mod_on_xspice.sh

использовал этот скрипт, а потом добавить его в сервис, но снова мимо проблема с Xspice его нету, а установить не получается нашел способ установить https://s3hh.wordpress.com/2014/04/18/xspice-in-containers/ ,но выдает ошибку на репозиторий, когда обновляюсь в итоге нашел программу с исходниками, раскидал по всем папкам, где должны быть файлы, но так этот метод и не сработал, подскажите, что не так

```
#!/bin/bash

export DISPLAY=:4

/usr/bin/Xspice --port 5900 --disable-ticketing $DISPLAY &
/home/ubuntu/Desktop/mqtt/mod
```

Comment: Куда, по вашему мнению, программа, запускающаяся на старте системы, должна выводить графику с точки зрения идеологии юникса?

Answer (score 2):

Для графического приложения нужен графический сервер. Как вариант - запустить виртуальный.

Создайте скрипт `/home/ubuntu/Desktop/mqtt/mod_on_xspice.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

export DISPLAY=:4

/usr/bin/Xspice --port 5900 --disable-ticketing $DISPLAY &
/home/ubuntu/Desktop/mqtt/mod
```

И запускайте сервис через него.

Comment: не было Xspice скачал закинул его в папки где должны находиться но все рано не работает

Comment: Его установить вообщето нужно)) https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/xserver-xspice/filelist

Comment: https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/xserver-xspice

Comment: я скачал файл и закинул их в те пути которые вы показали  у меня архитектура не amd64 у меня однаплатник beaglebone у него вроде arm7

Comment: если пишу команду apt install xserver-xspice
    выходит такая ошибка
E: Unable to locate package xserver-xspice

Comment: На древней убунте попробуй Xvnc

Answer (score 0):

Странно, что у вас не получилось запустить с root правами сервис, systemd службы по дефолту запускаются с root правами, но не всегда. Попробуйте добавить параметр User=root в файл сервиса:

```
[Unit]
Description=c program service

[Service]
ExecStart=/путь до вашей программы
User=root

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Назовите его например my_c_program.service и сохраните в /lib/systemd/system

```
sudo systemctl start my_c_program.service
sudo systemctl stop my_c_program.service
sudo systemctl enable my_c_program.service
```

Comment: я исправил, но все равно не получилось ,это может быть связано с тем, что пытаюсь запустить программу с графикой

Comment: Ладно, разберешься позже с systemd. Просто добавь в файл /etc/rc.local
строку с запуском своего скрипта:
/home/ubuntu/Desktop/mqtt/mod &

Comment: попробовал но все равно не хочет работать

Comment: Покажи что в логах при запуске systemd и при запуске rc.local.
journalctl -u runscript.service

Comment: journalctl -u runscript.service                                                                                                        -- Logs begin at Mon 2019-05-27 08:54:08 UTC, end at Mon 2019-05-27 10:33:52 UTC
-- No entries --

Comment: с графикой? с граффикой там же иксы ещё надо запустить

Comment: @eri, существовал (существует?) Специальный пакет для запуска графических приложений в режиме headless. По-моему называется Xvfb.

Comment: @0andriy последний раз запускался на Xspice. Удобней vfb в плане подключится потыкать мышкой